# Construction of flat functions

Tags: analysis, functions, derivatives, smooth-functions

The popular function

f(x) = e^(-1/x^2)  when x is nonzero
= 0           when x = 0

defines one that is flat at 0 (all derivatives vanish there).
My question is: How do I construct a (differentiable) function that is flat at more than one points, say, at 0 and 1, simultaneously.

In general, how do I construct a (differentiable) function that is flat at countably infinitely many points?

I am thinking of this problem in the lines of the Pasting Lemma. As for example, taking different functions flat at the points 0 and 1, and then gluing them. But, doing so might be a compromise on differentiability at the point where the pasting is done. How do I get around this problem?

Comment: $e^{-1/x^2}e^{-1/(1-x)^2}$ works for $0$ and $1$. If a function is flat at all rational points it is the zero function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks. Your example gives a function that is flat at every point between 0 and 1. What if we don't want flatness at some points between 0 and 1, say, in some neighbourhood of 1/ 2? Is there some way to achieve this?

Comment: Kavi Rama Murthy's function is only flat at two points: $0$ and $1$, nowhere else. And the same trick can be immediately extended to any finite number of points. For a countable number of points, you would need to make sure the product didn't converge to $0$ over some unintended range.